# What is the difference between $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand() and Get-Command?

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm playing with proxy functions and I would like to completely understand all the code I am looking at.

Given this:

```
$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData
    (Get-Command Get-ChildItem)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
```

Here is a snippet of code from that output I don't understand:

```
$wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Get-ChildItem',
    [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
```

What is the different between **$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand()** and **Get-Command**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My belief (pure speculation) is that this is just more reliable / explicit.

It's likely that the cmldet `Get-Command` internally calls `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand()`.

A cmdlet can be overridden with another cmdlet of the same name, or a function, or an alias, that will take precedence over it.

Comment: hmm that makes a lot of sense. Still frustrating though how, in the articles I have read, everyone seems to consider the skeletal portions of the proxy function code a black box, I guess no one outside of the MS devs knows why its written this way or what the heck its really doing then?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that this gives you the ability to specify contextual items such as environment variables that are only applied when that context based call is made.  I believe that the Get-Command executes under the current global+user contexts.